# Symfony translation catalogue not loading

Tags: php, symfony

Good day everyone,

I just wanted to add the english translation to my Symfony2 Project (Version 2.6.11). I copied all the files from the translation office to my project and checked them by

> app/console translation:debug en [bundle]

Everything is fine over here, so I do get all the translations listed.

I embedded the *{_locale}*-Placeholder in my routes. Visiting http://localhost:8000/en I only ge the german page.

By dumping these values:

```
dump($request->getLocale());
$trans = $this->get('translator');
dump($trans->getLocale());
```

I get *"en"* and *"en"* as the result. So I do not understand, why the debugger lists correct translations with the given locale and the web frontend does not do so.

In cached files (app/cache/dev/translations/catalouge.en[...].php) there are also only the german translations.

So summarizing translation:debug outputs the correct translations and although the translator has got the correct locale, every time the fallback locale is shown.

Anyone an Idea?

Comment: Yes, of course.. sereval times. Without warm-up and manually deleted cache folder.

Comment: Can you show where the files are placed and how they are named?

Comment: Argh.. got the mistake: Had the LexikTranslationBundle still enabled..